# Why is decimal not a primitive type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Why is `decimal` not a primitive type?

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(decimal).IsPrimitive);
```

outputs `false`.

It is a base type, it's part of the specifications of the language, but not a primitive. What primitive type(s) do represent a `decimal` in the framework? An `int` for example has a field `m_value` of type `int`. A `double` has a field `m_value` of type `double`. It's not the case for `decimal`. It seems to be represented by a bunch of `int`s but I'm not sure.

Why does it look like a primitive type, [behaves like a primitive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/types#primitive-types) (except in a [couple of cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192833/why-decimal-is-not-a-valid-attribute-parameter-type)) but is not a primitive type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although not a direct answer, the documentation for `IsPrimitive` lists what the primitive types are:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

A similar question was asked here:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233001-typeof-decimal-isprimitive-false-bug-feature

Answer quoted from Jon Skeet:

> The CLR doesn't need to have any intrinsic knowledge about the decimal
>   type - it treats it just as another value type which happens to have
>   overloaded operators. There are no IL instructions to operate directly
>   on decimals, for instance.

To me, it seems as though `decimal` is a type that must exist for a language/runtime wanting to be CLS/CLI-compliant (and is hence termed "primitive" because it is a base type with keyword support), but the actual implementation does not require it to be truly "primitive" (as in the CLR doesn't think it is a primitive data type).

Comment: Yes I read this link. The first link I gave - althought for VB - lists however `decimal` as a primitive. Trying my snippet in VB returned me `false` also. Maybe there's an error in the specs for VB (or they're out of date...)!

Comment: @Guillaume Yes I saw that link, I think it might hinge on where the definition of "primitive" lies. In the CLR, it is not a primitive type, however it appears to be described as one if you consider just the specification (of which the CLR is an implementation).

Comment: I think the confusion _may_ lie in the terminology; as in, framework primitive types being one thing, and 'built-in' types of a .NET supported language being another but considered 'primitive' in a different sense in the context of that language?

Comment: @GrantThomas I agree, this is also my best guess and I hopefully convey this in the answer.

Comment: I quite like your second link. The answer from Nicholas Paladino also makes sense.

Comment: A more interesting case is `string`, which should IMHO be regarded as a primitive type since it and `Array` are the only two variable-size types, and its storage is different from that of `Array`.

Comment: Also because CLR does not consider `decimal` as a primitive type, therefore there are no IL instructions  for manipulating `decimal` values - the `checked/unchecked` operators/statements/compiler switches will have no effect.

Answer (score 13):

Decimal is a 128 bit data type, which can not be represented natively on a computer hardware. For example  a 64-bit computer architecture generally has integer and addressing registers that are 64 bits wide, allowing direct support for 64-bit data types and addresses.

Wikipedia says that

> Depending on the language and its implementation, primitive data types
>   may or may not have a one-to-one correspondence with objects in the
>   computer's memory. However, one usually expects operations on basic
>   primitive data types to be the fastest language constructs there are.

In case of decimal it is just a composite datatype which utilizes integers internally, so its performance is slower than of datatypes that have a direct correlation to computer memory (ints, doubles etc).

Comment: I didn't think about the impact this data structure on the architecture... I'll try to find more info about this.

Comment: Although I understand the idea behind the answer, can this be proven on types such as `double` and `long` that are 63-bits wide on a 32-bit system? My point being that the CLR may not take this definition of primitive into account.

Comment: So essentially decimals can also become primitive when we will have 128 bit computers after a decade.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the below example ,

```
     int i = 5;
    float f = 1.3f;
    decimal d = 10;
```

If you put a debugger and verify the native instruction set,it would be

[image]

As you can see **int**,**float** all being a primitive type takes single instruction to perform the assignemnt operation whereas **decimal,string** being non primitive types takes more than one native instruction to perform this operation.