# Validate a decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
 public class MinimumSalaryAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly decimal _minValue;

        public MinimumSalaryAttribute(decimal minValue)
        {
            _minValue = minValue;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return (decimal)value > _minValue;
        }
    }
```

and then in my view:

```
[MinimumSalary(0M)]
public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

This would prevent users entering negative decimals.  However, I get a compiler error: "not a valid attribute type".  I understand the reason for this as described here: [Why "decimal" is not a valid attribute parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192833/why-decimal-is-not-a-valid-attribute-parameter-type)

What is the workaround in my vase?

Comment: Do you *really* need to use decimal here? Would you ever restrict a salary to 12.56? Just use `int`. Which means you can just use the normal `Range` attribute.

Comment: Are you sure the `IsValid` is valid? I'd say it should return true if `value >= _minValue`...

Comment: @PeterB, I have corrected this.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG, surely a monetary value should be a decimal - that it what it is for - isn't it? Is your suggestion just a hack? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well yes, it's a kind of a hack, but it's the least hacky way to achieve this. Only a hack will get around the fact you can't use a decimal for an attribute parameter.

Comment: Why not just `[Range(0, double.MaxValue)]`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I was thinking about that. Are there any pitfalls to this? I cannot think of any.  Thanks.

Comment: Only if its for Mark Zuckerberg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Range" annotation;
10.50D is min value,50.80D is max value...

```
[Range(10.50D,50.80D,ErrorMessage ="Error min")]
public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

Range attribute specifies the numeric range constraints for the value of a data field. It comes with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll)

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to work.  Could the downvoter explain what is wrong?

Comment: @w0051977 I would guess that the vote is because of the quality of the answer as it's just a code dump with no explanation of why it would work.

Comment: @DavidG, If I saw this answer, then I would upvote it and I will.  I find it clear and concise.  Maybe another paragraph would of helped.  Is there anything wrong with it in principle? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 Any post which is effectively only a code dump is not useful. This one answers your question but without explaining why you can use `double` or even that the numbers *are* `double`. So personally I don't think it's worthy of an upvote in it's current form.

Comment: @DavidG, fair enough.

Comment: @w0051977 Of course, there's nothing stopping pisi1001 [edit]ing this answer to make it much better, after all that's the entire point of this site!