# To match the data types of columns in the database and in the class

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

**Question:** what types of columns should I use in the database and in the class for the correct operation of the application?

Project: https://github.com/jhon65496/TypeDataCnsl01

**Used by** SQLite

There is a problem with the columns `IndexValue`, `Discount`. The goal is to get data from the database and perform calculations.

If:

- in the database, the columns `IndexValue`, `Discount` are of type `DECIMAL(10, 5),`;
- in the `Index` class, the fields `IndexValue`, `Discount`  are of type `string`.

then there are no problems and I get the data.

If

- in the database, the columns `IndexValue`, `Discount` are of type `DECIMAL(10, 5)`;
- in the **Index** class, the fields `IndexValue`, `Discount` are of type `decimal`.

I get an error when debugging.

Error:

> The recipient of the call has created an exception

The error occurs on the line

```
var items = indexesRepository.Items.toArray();
```

in the `Load Data()` method in the `IndexesViewModel' class.

```cs
public class IndexesViewModel
{   
    // ...
    // Code
    // ...
    
    public void LoadData()
    {         
        var items = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
        Indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(items);
    }
}
```

Is used:

- Console .NET Framework;
- System.Data.SQLite.

**Code**

`Index` class:

```cs
[Table("Indexes")]
public class Index 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // decimal
    // float        
    public decimal IndexValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }        
}
```

`DbContextIndexes`:

```cs
public class DbContextIndexes : DbContext
{
    static SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection;
    
    public DbContextIndexes() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Index> Indexes { get; set; }
}
```

`IndexesRepository`:

```cs
class IndexesRepository 
{
    private readonly DbSet<Index> _Set;
    DbContextIndexes _db;

    public IndexesRepository(DbContextIndexes db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _Set = _db.Set<Index>();
    }

    private IQueryable<Index> items;

    public virtual IQueryable<Index> Items
    {
        get
        {
            items = _Set;
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`IndexesViewModel`:

```cs
public class IndexesViewModel
{   
    IndexesRepository indexesRepository;
    
    DbContextIndexes DataContextApp;

    public IndexesViewModel()
    {
        this.DataContextApp = new DbContextIndexes();
        indexesRepository   = new IndexesRepository(this.DataContextApp);

        LoadData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Index> indexes;

    public ObservableCollection<Index> Indexes
    {
        get { return indexes; }
        set 
        {
            indexes = value;                
        }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {         
        var items = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray(); // <== Тут ошибка !!!
        Indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(items);
    }
}
```

SQL indexes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Indexes" 
(
    "Id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "Name"  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "IndexValue"    DECIMAL(10, 5),
    "Discount"  DECIMAL(10, 5),
    "Description"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

`packages.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

`App.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=dbAppIndexes.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Screenshot #1:

[image]

Screenshot #2:

[image]

---

## Update-1

It's working.
Replaced the comma `,` with a period `.`.

What is the point?

Can I store data in a database only with a semicolon?
can I not store data in a database ?
Which types should I choose to store the IndexValue and Discount fields.

[image]

---

## Update-2. Added: `CultureInfo'.

Result: it doesn't work

Does not work.
Project: https://github.com/jhon65496/TypeDataCnsl01/tree/CultureInfo01

I downloaded the Sqlite application from the official website.
I created a SQLLite database using an SQL query.
I have created an application.
In the application, I did not create the code used by **CultureInfo** .

Added in `Main()` in  **program.cs**:

```cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Full code

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        IndexesViewModel indexesViewModel = new IndexesViewModel();
    }
}
```

Error text

```
Message = The recipient of the call has created an exception.

Internal exception 1:
FormatException: The input string had an incorrect format.
```

The full text of the error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Сообщение = Адресат вызова создал исключение.
  Источник = mscorlib
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetTypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]

Внутреннее исключение 1:
FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

[image]

---

## Update-3

Format: Russia

[image]

---

## Update-4.

Description: `Prop: [NotMapped], public string FormattedIndexValue`

Error:
*Message = The recipient of the call has created an exception.

FormatException: The input string had an incorrect format.*

Project: https://github.com/jhon65496/TypeDataCnsl01/tree/PropNotMapString01

I didn't quite understand the phrase:
*Just note that in **Linq** queries you can't use it in things like `Select` and `Where`, etc. where it translates to **SQL**, use `IndexValue`.*
I'll do as I understand.

I have deleted unnecessary fields.
Now the model looks like this;

**Index.cs**

```cs
[Table("Indexes")]
public class Index 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal IndexValue { get; set; }        
    private readonly CultureInfo _uiCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    [NotMapped]
    public string FormattedIndexValue
    {
        get => IndexValue.ToString(_uiCultureInfo);
        set => IndexValue = decimal.Parse(value, _uiCultureInfo);
    }
}
```

**Table "Indexes"**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Indexes" (
    "Id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "Name"  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "IndexValue"    DECIMAL(10, 5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

| Id | Name | IndexValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name-1 | 10,10 |

Testing Log
If the table has `IndexValue = 10`     - the application reads the data;
If the table has `IndexValue = 10.10`  - the application reads the data;
If the table has `IndexValue = 10,10`  - error!!!.

**IndexesViewModel**(I didn't make any changes)

```cs
public void LoadData()
{         
    var items = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
    Indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(items);
}
```

**IndexesRepository**(I didn't make any changes)

```cs
class IndexesRepository 
    {

        private readonly DbSet<Index> _Set;
        DbContextIndexes _db;

        public IndexesRepository(DbContextIndexes db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _Set = _db.Set<Index>();
        }

        private IQueryable<Index> items;
        public virtual IQueryable<Index> Items
        {
            get
            {
                items = _Set;
                return items;
            }
            set
            {
                items = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Error description**

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Сообщение = Адресат вызова создал исключение.
  Источник = mscorlib
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetTypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)


  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]

Внутреннее исключение 1:
FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely going to be a difference in regional settings between the database server and the server or client where your .Net code is executing. By default .Net will be using the system region settings, which includes settings for number formats, particularly the "Digit Grouping Symbol" and the "Decimal symbol", plus to a lesser degree the "List separator".

Between countries, some use "." for a decimal separator and "," for a grouping separator, while other countries use "," for decimal, and "." for grouping, which makes things really flipping confusing when a server set up for one receives numbers formatted for the other. Internally a decimal is a decimal, the symbol settings affect how these are displayed as strings or parsed from strings. Since EF is effectively building SQL to run against the database, this becomes a problem because at the end of the day it will be turning your decimal values into a string, which the DB won't understand unless it's using the same number formatting.

The first option to solve the problem is ensure that both servers, (assuming an ASP.Net application) web server and db server are using the same regional culture settings, so expecting the same number format.

If that option is not practical, then you can update the web server's culture setting programatically on initialization using:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

If the web server is set/hosted in Russia or Eastern Europe an the database installation defaulted to US English number formatting.

For web applications themselves where clients may be using a system with different UI culture settings you will need to know what UI cultures each client is using when they log in or based on the request headers from the browser and use that to parse and format any decimal values coming in and out  of the client browser.

Edit:

If you do the above the force the application thread to use "en-US" with the "." decimal separator, the issue is that if you later use `ToString()` or `Parse` on a string representation of the decimal it will be expecting the "." as the decimal separator, where users in your region might expect to use ",".  To get around this you don't need to change the IndexValue / Discount to strings with a "ru-RU" culture in the formatting, but rather add an unmapped property to handle getting and setting the value as a formatted string:

```
public decimal IndexValue { get; set; }
private readonly CultureInfo _uiCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
[NotMapped]
public string FormattedIndexValue
{
    get => IndexValue.ToString(_uiCultureInfo);
    set => IndexValue = decimal.Parse(value, _uiCultureInfo);
}
```

This tells EF that there isn't a column named FormattedIndexValue, it is like a computed app-only value. Just note that in Linq queries you cannot use it in things like `Select` and `Where` etc. where that translates to SQL, use IndexValue.

Comment: I've been thinking about it. 
I don't understand how to apply this solution in my project. 
I use the following components: 
 **1.** Net.Framework(Console, WPF, WinForms) 
**2.**EF6(Framework) **3.**DB: SQLite(required).
---- ---- ---- --- ----  
 **Questions:** **1.** How can your solution be applied in my project?
**2.** Do I need to change anything in the components? For example, **EF6(Framework)** is replaced by EFCore. I would not like to do this, but if it is absolutely necessary, then it can be done...

Comment: Was the database file copied from a different machine, or how are you getting the data into the database in the first place?  SQLLite is usually used for embedded databases so by default it should just work, defaulting to the same culture settings as your application. Does your code currently have any code using `CultureInfo` anywhere?  It soulds like your application is using en-US culture with "." as the separator but the database somehow has commas for the decimal separator. EF is expecting to read periods, so if EF isn't writing the values in, what is?

Comment: If the database has Commas and was imported/copied from a ru-RU or similar UI culture machine, you can use the above code in the answer using `... = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");` .... in the app.xaml.cs `OnStartup()` method (if WPF) or `Main()` in a  program.cs. (Basically wherever your application entry point is.)

Comment: See **Update-2**

Comment: That seems very odd if the database is created on the same machine. I suspect it will work if you change the culture setting to "en-US" though that isn't really a fix as I would expect that the SQLLite EF provider and database should work with localized decimal characters. I will have a look at your project and doco to see if anything stands out to explain this. Surely many development teams in "," decimal separator nations are using SQLIte & EF without such issues.

Comment: I probably found a similar problem.
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19982#issuecomment-589870336

But I do not know how to adapt the solution to my project.
In EF6, there is no `HasConversion<double>();`.
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I have been doing a bit of digging and it seems that this may be a imposed limitation by the System.Data.SQLLite implementation providers, it seems they are not using regional settings but insisting on a "standard" "." decimal separator: "https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/bff30450cbc1c8ee47d43058c69232b9cbf713e66c9b52caba2cc88ab52dfbad"  It does look like the EF Core provider team though *has* addressed regional settings: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1057

Comment: That is honestly really annoying because this isn't a case of passing strings into the provider but preventing the provider from building valid SQL meaning for it to work you would need to run as "en-US" and manually format all decimal values to replace the "." with "," in and out of the UI.  I'd honestly give the .Net Core / EF Core a go with your test project and make the argument to use that if it's working better.

Comment: See **Update-3**

Comment: What if I make some kind of transformation in the `IndexValue` and `Discount` properties of my model?
Is it possible? If it is possible, could you tell me how to do it?
I don't understand how to adapt the example...
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471541/10530657
Example: 
```cs
public String MinimumValue
{
    get
    {
        return minimumValueDecimal.ToString();
    }

    set
    {
        minimumValueDecimal = Decimal.Parse(value);
    }
}

private decimal minimumValueDecimal;
```

Comment: Yes, though if you have to set the Thread UICulture to "en-US" to keep the SqlLite provider happy with "." for decimal, then `Decimal.Parse()` and `Decimal.Tostring()` will expect and use "." as well. Your property getter-setter would need `var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU"); return minimumValueDecimal.ToString(culture);` and likewise on the setter to parse the comma-decimal character.

Comment: In the example I suggested, the property is of type `string`.
**1.** I thought: why use `CultureInfo`?
Maybe I'll just make the `IndexValue` property in the `Index` class not of the `decimal` type, but of the `string` type?
In other words: `public string Index Value {get; set;}`
And if I need to perform a mathematical operation, then I will do `decimal result = Decimal.Parse(Index.IndexValue) * 2;`

Would that be a big violation? Or is it possible to do this?

**2.** Can I do the same in the `IndexValue` database not with the `decimal` type, but with the `string` type?

Comment: The raw value should be left a decimal. The whole "." vs "," character issue is a presentation and transposition issue where the SqlLite provider is expecting a "." without considering culture. With the default culture set to "en-US" it will provide ".", so I would leave IndexValue & Discount as `decimal` but expose an additional non-mapped `string` property like `[NotMapped] FormattedIndex { get { var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU"); return IndexValue.ToString(cultureInfo); }` this way if you need a string getter or setter that can handle to/from desured UI format.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of such an unmapped property for the formatting.

Comment: See **Update-4**.
You said that solving the problem can be effective.
Will the system work: The NET Framework application works with the database via a DLL that supports EFCore.
Subject: Application(Net Framework) <-> DLL(EFCore) <->SQLite.

Comment: The SqlLite database table looks like it will need to store the decimal values with "." which you then use the "Formatted" property to handle displaying it in your application with the desired "," and parsing any strings with comma back to the decimal. A .net Framework application can use an .Net Core+EF Core assembly, but only up to EF Core 6 or maybe 7 as .Net Standard 2.0 was dropped. I would first check with a simple app if EF Core works with the database as you have it.

Comment: Sorry... 
I didn't understand the message... Clarify what you wanted to say...
my goals: 
- the user can enter numbers separated by ",";
- the application can read data from the database;
- the application can perform calculations with data from the database.

Your message that I didn't understand:
`The SqlLite database table looks like it will need to store the decimal values with "." which you then use the "Formatted" property to handle displaying it in your application with the desired "," and parsing any strings with comma back to the decimal. `

Comment: This: "If the table has IndexValue = 10.10 - the application reads the data;" You need to use values like 10.10 in the table, then in your application you use that FormattedIndexValue property to get and set the value relating to your UI so it will display it as "10,10" in your application.