# Give object as parameter for test

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

I trying to write a test that checks that a method isn't overwritten incorrectly in derived classes. So I tried the following. But no matter what I try it doesn't seem to allow me to "inject" my object.

```
[Theory]
[xxxData(new BaseClass())]
[xxxData(new DerivedClass())]
public void Test_Stuff(BaseClass obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A complete guide that sends complex objects as a parameter to Test methods [complex types in Unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413307/7487135)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming I understand your goal, I see two ways:

1. Using `InlineDataAttribute` and passing Types
2. Using `MemberDataAttribute` (PropertyData in xunit.net v1)

   ```
   [Theory]
   [InlineData(typeof(BaseClass))]
   [InlineData(typeof(DerivedClass))]
   public void Test_Stuff(Type type/*BaseClass obj*/)
   {
       var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as BaseClass;
       CheckConstrain(obj);
   }


   [Theory]
   [MemberData("GetObjects")]
   public void Test_Stuff2(BaseClass obj)
   {
       CheckConstrain(obj);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetObjects
   {
       get
       {
          return new[] 
          {
           new object[] { new BaseClass() },
           new object[] { new DerivedClass() }
          };
       }
   }

   private static void CheckConstrain(BaseClass baseClass)
   {
       Assert.True(baseClass.Foo() <= 1);
   }
   ```

See also this related answer [Pass complex parameters to [Theory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093843/pass-complex-parameters-to-theory)