# xunit.net - how to pass complex object to a test?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

I need to pass a complex object (`Dictionary<Decimal, Int32>`, in my case) to a test method. Can it be done? 
Yes, I read available answers here, none of them work with dictionaries, not PropertyData, not ClassData, and InlineData only allows compile-time constants 
I use xunit.net 1.9.2

Comment: Huh ? What have you tried? `[Theory, PropertyData("Provider")` works for me and lots of people including stuff far more exotic than a Dictionary. Are you returning `object[]` from you Property?

Comment: @RubenBartelink so I need to return object[], not IEnumerable<object[]> as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093843/pass-complex-parameters-to-theory?

Comment: No, when I say `return`, I meant `yield return` :P Yes, IEnumerable. I (because you didnt give any exception info, stack traces, output window messages) was having a wild stab that the issue could be returning e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable<object>` or something other that `object[]`. (Saying result should be `IEnumerable<object[]>`, while technically correct would have been misleading suggestion given one normally implements it by returning an array of `object[]` (which implements `IEnumerable<object[]>`). Bottom line: Need to provide info so Q can be answered, not guessed at.

Comment: @RubenBartelink you're right. I'll post my code that didn't work

Comment: @RubenBartelink I must have been wrong. using `PropertyData` attribute and returning `return new[] { new object[] { new Dictionary<Decimal, Int32>() { ... } } }` for test data worked just fine

Comment: Unless there's a cast to `object[]`, the fact that the result is marked as just `Object` can make it very errorprone - but in general ther's always a clear message IME. Good you're sorted.