# Passing Guid to Test Method

Tags: c#, guid, xunit.net

```
[InlineData(Guid.Empty)]
[InlineData("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]
[Theory]
public async Task Get_ValidateInput(Guid Id) 
{ ... }
```

`[InlineData(Guid.Empty)]` gives compile time error:

> `CS0182 - An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.`

`[InlineData("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]` gives runtime error:

> `Specified method not supported.`

Comment: Have you tried taking a string parameter to your method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716303/xunit-theory-guids-as-parametr

Comment: Bug reports: [one](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1803), [two](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1781).  Add your own if an update doesn't fix it.

Comment: `default(Guid)` is the same as `Guid.Empty` here, and will compile

Comment: "xxxx" is a string.. it will *never* be the same as a Guid and can therefor never be compilied. That being said.. A guid is not a constant.. It will never be (unless it's default Guid) - it's by *design* a instantiated class - it's not a primitive take more in depth look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926573/how-to-declare-a-constant-guid-in-c

Answer (score 2):

workaround!

```
    [InlineData(null)]                                    //null
    [InlineData("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]  //Empty Guid
    [InlineData("")]                                      //Empty string
    [Theory]
    public async Task Get_ValidateInput(object Id)
    {
        //test
    }
```