# XUnit InlineData with Objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, xunit.net

Recently we have been trying Unit Testing in a new project, now that we want to pass a Object to our test method with `[InlineData]`, so we can utilize the same test method multiple times with multiple different data inputs.

`[ClassData]` and `[MemberData]` are also available, but do not seem to offer a solution, as to my understanding.

Basically, is there a way to pass Objects with XUnit, like so:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new Object { Attribute = 1 })]
public void Test(Object obj) 
{
    // Assert
    Xunit.Assert.NotNull(obj.Attribute);
}
```

Or is this not the correct convention or usage?

Passing `int`'s and `string`'s works fine using `[InlineData]`

Comment: and this article http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/

Comment: A complete guide that sends complex objects as a parameter to Test methods [complex types in Unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413307/7487135)

Comment: Please refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093843/pass-complex-parameters-to-theory