# Introducing Generic Types to a constructor inheriting from non-Generic class

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

### *Question:*

Is there a work around to be able to use generics in the constructor of a class that inherits from a class that doesn't have generic types defined?

---

### *Explanation:*

I am creating a new custom attribute inheriting from the ValidationAttribute class. I want to use generic types in the constructor as seen below:

```
DateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute {

   public void DateValidationAttribute <TData>(Expression<Func<TData, DateTime?>> property){ ... }

}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be allowed as the TData and TProperty generic types aren't recognized as generics. In addition I cannot define the generics in the class definition as it inherits from the ValidationAttribute class. The error I get is that TData and TProperty is not defined.

---

### *Goal:*

The goal of passing and expression down to have a strongly typed way of passing attribute names. I am writing this attribute to compare two properties of a class. The implementation below is what it looks like. Beneath that is how I want the implementation to look like:

```
Current:

public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }

[DateValidation("ToDate")]
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
```

---

```
Goal:

public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }

[DateValidation(prop => prop.ToDate)]
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "child of class"?

Comment: Also know that you cannot make a constructor generic, you will have to make the type generic. Could you take a step back and tell us what you're trying to accomplish, instead of how you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  I reworked the question to better explain points you were unclear about and added the objective of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your goal will not work because the types that can be specified in an attribute usage [are limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types), and `Expression` is not one of those types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use decimal values as attribute params in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507528/use-decimal-values-as-attribute-params-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-support for generics in attributes is the least of your problems. Attributes can only have a specific [subset of types (primitives, enums, String, Type and single-dimensional arrays) as constructor arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types), not lambdas. So even if you could use generics you could not do what you're trying to do.

Consider using a string as constructor parameter and using `nameof()`, e.g.:

```
[DateValidation(nameof(ToDate))]
```

This approach keeps the names in sync with the real property name and thus you get the safety you want when refactoring etc.

Comment: Here's the list of types you can use in attributes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types